# single event listener for multiple events

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, event-listener

I have a JS function that is adding a variable number of sections.  In each section I have an input with id and name set to "type_" + i where i is the section index

```
 var input=document.createElement('select');
                            input.id ="type_" + i
                            input.name="type_" + i
                            input.required = true 
                            input.classList.add("selects")
                            myPre.appendChild(input);
                            var myInput = document.getElementById('type_' + i)
                            var prefix = document.createTextNode('Media Type      : ')
                            myInput.parentNode.insertBefore(prefix, myInput);
                            var option = document.createElement("option");
                            option.text = "";
                            myInput.add(option);
                            var option = document.createElement("option");
                            option.text = "IMAGE";
                            myInput.add(option);
                            var option = document.createElement("option");
                            option.text = "VIDEO";
                            myInput.add(option);
                            var option = document.createElement("option");
                            option.text = "IFRAME";
                            myInput.add(option);
```

This is for an input screen.  Based on which option is selected (IMAGE, VIDEO or IFRAME) I need to either upload a file  for IMAGE or VIDEO or input a link for  IFRAME

This is the conditional JS for file upload

```
                            var input=document.createElement('input');
                            input.type="file";
                            input.id ="mediaSec_" + i
                            input.name ="mediaSec_" + i
                            input.required = true 
                            input.classList.add("files")
                            myPre.appendChild(input);
                            var myInput = document.getElementById('mediaSec_' + i)
                            var prefix = document.createTextNode('   Upload Media    : ')
                            myInput.parentNode.insertBefore(prefix, myInput);
                            //var br = document.createElement('BR')
                            //myInput.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", br);
```

and this the conditional JS to add a link address

```
var input=document.createElement('input');
                            input.type="text";
                            input.id ="link_" + i
                            input.name ="link_" + i
                            input.classList.add("links")
                            input.placeholder = "add iframe https://" 
                            myPre.appendChild(input);
                            var myInput = document.getElementById('link_' + i)
                            var prefix = document.createTextNode('   Link Address : ')
                            myInput.parentNode.insertBefore(prefix, myInput);
                            var br = document.createElement('BR')
                            myInput.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", br);
```

Do I need to do this in a separate function?  Can I do this with one listener or do I need to have a listener for each section? How would I pass the id?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by single event listener for multiple event .. I guess you mean the handler that handles what happens on the event ? If my assumption is correct then yes you can do that, you can make one handler and you could check the type of the file/input submitted. If it is of type image/jpeg you can trigger the input for images.. if it video for video if its string for iframe